# Lustre file system: how many OSTs?

Tags: parallel-processing, lustre

Is there a way, besides bugging the sys admins, to determine how many Lustre OSTs a parallel system has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lfs` utility will give you this info.
I believe `lfs osts` specifically lists the OSTs

Answer (score 3):

Also, `lfs df` and `lfs df -i` will print the space and inode usage per OST, respectively.